# I want to plot several curves in pgfplots and I have problem with markers

Tags: pgfplots

I want to skip some of markers, but not skip Coordinates. 
For example if we have 24 Coordinates I dont need 24 marker, I need 12 marker with 24 Coordinates.
How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{report}‎
‎\usepackage{pgfplots}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}‎‎
‎\begin{semilogxaxis}
‎\addplot file{ar0.dat};
‎%ar0 is a file with 24 coordinates
‎\end{semilogxaxis}‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
‎\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably best to provide `ar0.dat` in your question to give people something to play with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key `mark repeat=<each nth>` allows to draw marks only at each nth position.

You could use it by means of

```
\addplot+[mark repeat=2] .... ;
```

in your example.

Comment: @sayros the best way to say thanks is to upvote, and accept the answer by clicking on the green check mark